# "click image to display its id" and its pitfall

Tags: javascript, scope, onclicklistener

The title seems like a piece of cake, but that is not exactly what I am trying to ask. I just can't think of a better title, if you have any after reading the following, please comment and I will update the title.
With jQuery, it is quite easy to do this, because `click()` passes `this` parameter,

```
$('img').click(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id')})
```

I was trying to do this using vanilla javascript, and encountered some pitfall

```
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
l = imgs.length;
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click',function(){console.log(imgs[i].id)});
}
```

This won't work because every listner will be trying to `console.log(imgs[l].id)`.

I have worked out a workaround:

```
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
l = imgs.length;
listener_generator = function(id){
  var s = function(){
   console.log(id);
  };
  return s;
};
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click',listener_generator(imgs[i].id));
}
```

For learning purpose, I kind of remember when I read some javascript book, besides the approach above, there are other ways to do this, but I can't find it now. My question is, is there any other way to do this? And which one is the best practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic closure problem, which you stumbled into solving perhaps unintentionally.

The problem with this code:

```
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('click',function(){console.log(imgs[i].id)});
}
```

is basically that `console.log(imgs[i].id)` is not evaluated immediately, it is evaluated *when the event listener is triggered*. What this means is that you have lots of expressions that refer to `i`, but since they don't execute until the event listener fires, they all hold the exact same value of `i` (the last value it had at the end of the for loop).

To get around this, you need to "close over" the value of `i` to sort of capture its value *in the for loop* instead of later on when the event listener fires. There are multiple ways to do this - my preferred method is to create an anonymous function that executes for every iteration of the for loop, like this:

```
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
    (function(_i){
        imgs[_i].addEventListener('click',function(){console.log(imgs[_i].id)});
    })(i);
}
```

You've basically accidentally solved this by creating a closure, only you're doing it with a named function instead of an anonymous one, but the result is the same. At runtime, the for loop calls a function which "captures" the value of `i` in a closure instead of deferring it until the event listener fires.

[Here is an excellent post with more detail about how closures work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

The first code should work just if you're replacing `img[i]` by `this` inside click event to refer to the current img :

```
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
l = imgs.length;

for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('click',function(){console.log(imgs[i].id)});
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

l = imgs.length;

for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click',function(){alert(this.id)});
}
```

```html
<img src='http://tny.im/3Qp' id='img_1' />
<img src='http://tny.im/3Qp' id='img_2' />
<img src='http://tny.im/3Qp' id='img_3' />
<img src='http://tny.im/3Qp' id='img_4' />
```